# SQLite docs-like figure

Tags: table-of-contents

I find SQLite docs very visual and I'd like to create one figure with the same format.
[image: SQLite select docs (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)]

Also, if it's possible, I'd like to place the "conditionals" that are fulfilled to take that path:
[image: SQLite docs with conditional]

Comment: See https://ctan.org/topic/formal-spec and make your choice.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A short google search led me to [this question at softwareengineering.SX](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/195720) which links to the [`rail` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/rail). Also, the newer `syntaxdi` package might be of interest.

Comment: If you want to do it all in tikz, have a look at the tutorial in ch. 5 in the pgfmanual https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf

Comment: You can generate tikz-code with a tool for EBNF: https://github.com/pyeatt/ebnf2tikz .

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I've found [syntaxdi](https://ctan.org/pkg/syntaxdi), and also the original [rail](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/rail) package, as @JasperHabicht have said. I'll try it with those packages.

Answer (score 1):

As [suggested by Jasper Habicht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/653099/sqlite-docs-like-figure/653115#comment1627684_653099), the [rail](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/rail) package did indeed have everything that I needed.

I was able to achieve the following:

[image: Compiled output, rendering the below code]

via:

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{rail}
        ([waterlogged=false] () | [waterlogged=true] 'WATERLOGGED' ) \\
        material
    \end{rail}
    \caption{Modifier concatenation}
\end{figure}
```

The only bad thing is that I need to compile it with the rail program every time I change something.